# Storing the count of each word occurring in a text file

Tags: python

I want to store the count of each word occurring in a text file in a dictionary. I mean

```
fob= open('D:/project/report.txt','r')
```

I am able to store the lines into a list, but I need to split these lines into individual words and finally store their count (like in a ditionary).

```
lst=fob.radlines()

#This doesn't work, gives error
#AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' 
mylst=lst.split()
```

How can I do that ? And what's the efficient way to do this ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python `2.7+`

```
from collections import Counter

with open('D:/project/report.txt','r') as fob:
    c = Counter(word for line in fob for word in line.split())
```

For Python `2.5+`

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(int)

with open('D:/project/report.txt','r') as fob:
    for line in fob:
        for word in line.split():
            dd[word] += 1
```

For older pythons or people that hate `defaultdict`

```
d = {}

with open('D:/project/report.txt','r') as fob:
    for line in fob:
        for word in line.split():
            d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1
```